# How to create a sin wave with upper and lower amplitude bounds

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, trigonometry

I can't for the life of my wrap my head around this seemingly easy problem.

I am trying to create a sine wave with upper and lower bounds for the amplitude (ie. highest point is 3 and lowest point is 0.4)

Using regular math I am able to get a sine wave in an array from 1 to -1 but I don't know how to change those bounds.

```
    static int MAX_POINTS = 100;
static int CYCLES = 1;
static double[] list = new double[100];

 public static void SineCurve()
  {
    double phaseMultiplier = 2 * Math.PI * CYCLES / MAX_POINTS; 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_POINTS; i++)
    {
      double cycleX = i * phaseMultiplier;
      double sineResult = Math.sin(cycleX);
      list[i]= sineResult;

    }

    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
  }
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would use simple math, just nothing more than addition and multiplication -- the multiplication to expand or shrink the range to the desired value and the addition to translate it to the desired center. You can do this if you try drawing it first on paper with pencil.

Comment: In fact if you use paper and pencil and play with multipliers, you'll likely solve this and also gain a better understanding of what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amplitude (multiplier of sin(x) value) is half the difference between the highest and lowest values you want.  In your case

```
amplitude = (3 - 0.4)/2
```

which is `1.3`.  Then zero offset is the lowest value plus the amplitude, which makes it `1.7` in your case.

The equation you want to graph is then

```
1.3 * sin(x) + 1.7
```

Comment: Thanks Jim! ... although I feel pretty dumb now.